# Can I check my eBook reader's battery level?

Tags: usb, power-management, battery

I have an eBook reader that I connect to my laptop on USB to charge it and to load eBooks.

While it's charging, the screen goes off and I can only see whether the battery is done loading or not. I would like to be able to check the battery level directly on my laptop.

I tried running `upower --dump` and I also looked at XFCE's Power Manager Plugin, but both only show the AC adapter and the laptop's own battery.

Is there a package I can install or a configuration I can change so I can see the battery of the USB device?

Comment: If your eBook reader is Android-based, then something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42274720/is-it-possible-to-query-device-state-ie-battery-charge-remaining-via-adb-shel) may help you out. I've never needed to check, but it's an interesting question.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! My device is a Tolino. I never knew it was Android-based, but apparently it is. Unfortunately it's not easy to connect with `adb`. I found [some instructions](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/android-boot-image.htm) but they involve modifying the boot image, and I'm not willing to risk doing that.

Comment: If that's the case, I'm afraid the answer is, "No, there's no package nor command that will enable you to do that." Sadly, there's no universal standard for reporting device battery charge or anything of that nature.